# Dúvida na inserção de dados realizando o relacionamento em outra tabela

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando inserir um Endereço na tabela adresses e referenciar com um Usuário já cadastrado sem Endereço na tabela user, por meio do _id que é gerado quando eu insiro um Endereço. Retorno esse _id e insiro ele na coluna adresses_id do Usuário que tiver o cpf igual ao do Usuário que irá receber esse Endereço.

```
WITH new_adresses AS (
INSERT INTO adresses (cep, street, neighborhood, city, state, number_house, complement)
        VALUES ('11222333', 'Rua Qualquer', 'Bairro', 'Cidade', 'ES', 777, 'Ed. Edifício')
        RETURNING _id)
        INSERT INTO users (adresses_id)
        VALUES (SELECT _id FROM new_adresses)
        WHERE cpf = '111.222.333-00'
```

Não estou conseguindo realizar a inserção dessa forma.
Está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
Posição: 281
```

Comment: se a intenção é atualizar "INSERT INTO users (adresses_id)" está incorreto, você deveria tentar um update

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda. Eu não estava realizando que teria que ser um UPDATE em vez de um INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava cometendo um erro utilizando o INSERT em vez do UPDATE SET. A query correta fica da seguinte forma:

```
WITH new_adresses AS (
INSERT INTO adresses (cep, street, neighborhood, city, state, number_house, complement)
        VALUES ('11222333', 'Rua do Karalho', 'Fon', 'YoCity', 'YO', 777, 'Ed. YoPredio')
        RETURNING _id)
        UPDATE users
        SET adresses_id = (SELECT _id FROM new_adresses)
 WHERE cpf = '139.127.217-00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você está fechando os parenteses no lugar errado, feche ele depois de informar o cpf, ficando:
...
VALUES (SELECT _id FROM new_adresses
WHERE cpf = '111.222.333-00')

Comment: Continua aparecendo o mesmo erro. Porque o WHERE serve pra selecionar em qual usuário, da tabela user, eu vou inserir o _id que foi retornado do endereço inserido.

Comment: Blz, bom que deu certo.